# powershell snippet equals true and false at the same time

Tags: powershell, if-statement, boolean

The following script:

```
Foreach($keyword in $Nagios."Row Labels"){
    if( -Not($Rt.SubjectLine | ?{$_ -match $keyword})){
    "$keyword is not there"
    }
}
```

matches true for all the content of $Rt.Subjectline

but that one returns the exact same result!:

```
Foreach($keyword in $Nagios."Row Labels"){
    if($Rt.SubjectLine | ?{$_ -match $keyword})){
    "$keyword is there"
    }
}
```

So my keywords are both there...and aren't ??? 
That doesn't make sense... what am I doing wrong ?

Basically I have an array which contains simple keywords like a=("one","two","three")
and I just want to check if any of those words match with anything the object $b.values....
seems simple yet powershell says the if statement is both true and false??

what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget this question, I had a brain fart. The string I use to compare isn't what I expected....